# Why does gzip -c give different results than gzip?

Tags: linux, compression, tar, gzip

I am writing unit tests for some code and found that a simple `gzip` is causing a difference in my results. Upon further investigation I found that `gzip` gives a different `.gz` file than `gzip -c` does. Why is this?

```
$ echo "foo" > bar
$ gzip bar
$ zcat bar.gz | gzip -c > test.gz
$ cmp bar.gz test.gz 
bar.gz test.gz differ: byte 4, line 1
$ stat bar.gz | grep Size
  Size: 28          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
$ stat test.gz | grep Size
  Size: 24          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
$ zcat bar.gz > foo1.txt
$ zcat test.gz > foo2.txt
$ cmp foo1.txt foo2.txt 
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: BTW, there no any point to use `-c` option if you piping to `gzip`. **man gzip**: `If no files are specified, or if a file name is "-", the standard input is compressed to the standard output.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gzipping a *file* will cause the original filename to be stored as part of the output header.

(By default, the modification time is stored as well, so even two identically created .gz files will differ.)